How Can I Add Memory to My RAG-Based Chatbot for Better Responsiveness?
I have developed a chatbot utilizing the RAG methodology. However, there is an issue where it does not retain previous conversations. Does anyone suggest integrating memory into the chatbot to enhance responsiveness?


However, there is an issue where it does not retain previous conversations. Does anyone suggest integrating memory into the chatbot to enhance responsiveness?

Add the most recent dialog turns to the prompt.

Here's an example from the Langchain documentation. They basically have utilities that take the latest prompt and reformulate it based on the chat history.
So for example, if the first question is, "What is deep learning?" and the second is, "Where can I learn more about it?" the LLM is instructed to modify the second prompt to be more clear using the context before answering it. In this case, it might change the second question to "Where can I learn more about deep learning?"
